# Problems registering a receiver with Microsoft Webhooks

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-webhooks

I'm trying to register a subscriber to events for using the [following](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/15/sending-webhooks-with-asp-net-webhooks-preview/) example. When I use the POST method, I get a bad request error (400), so I've attempted to visit the url where the request is sent and received using a browser and received the following stack trace:

When visiting

```
https://localhost:44300/api/webhooks/registrations
```

I get:

```
> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"General error
> during 'Get' operation: 'An error occurred while executing the command
> definition. See the inner exception for
> details.'.","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"
> at
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.DbWebHookStore`2.<GetAllWebHooksAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Controllers.WebHookRegistrationsController.<Get>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","innerException":{"message":"An
> error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"An error occurred while
> executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
> details.","exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException","stackTrace":"
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.<ExecuteAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ToArrayAsync>d__13`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.DbWebHookStore`2.<GetAllWebHooksAsync>d__5.MoveNext()","innerException":{"message":"An
> error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Invalid object name
> 'WebHooks.WebHooks'.","exceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","stackTrace":"
> at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__174_0(Task`1
> result)\r\n   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()\r\n
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()\r\n--- End of stack trace
> from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext()"}}}
```

Based on the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.Api/Controllers/WebHookRegistrationsController.cs#L37), my understanding is that the [line](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.Api/Controllers/WebHookRegistrationsController.cs#L310) below is problematic

```
string id = await _user.GetUserIdAsync(User);
```

One of my guesses is that Microsoft's Webhook library requires Identity to be installed (the application where I'm testing this uses SimpleMembership).

Is this the problem? Can this be resolved easily?

Comment: They key might be that the id of the user cannot be found based on the default claim (which is 'Name'). See the [WebHookUser](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom/WebHooks/WebHookUser.cs) class. In my case, since I used a different user identifier I had to set it to something else using `WebHookUser.IdClaimsType = Claims.AccessUserId;` in my web api bootstrapper (where `Claims.AccessUserId` is just a string "AccessUserId"

Comment: @PeterBons, Is there any way of doing this without having to modify the binaries? I.e. in WebAPIConfig or specific overload?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I did it immediately after the webhook initialization: `HttpConfiguration.InitializeCustomWebHooks();
            HttpConfiguration.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis(); WebHookUser.IdClaimsType = Claims.AccessUserId;`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work since I'm using SimpleMembership and not Identity (error: Claim' does not contain a definition for 'AccessUserId).

Comment: `AccessUserId` is just an example I had to use. In your case it could be UserId or Username or something. It is defined by the SimpleMembership provider