# AspNet WebHook Not Authenticating with Identity

Tags: c#, webhooks, identity

I have webhooks using the out of the box auth from the default Web MVC Projects.

I have now tried to port that into a Web API using Identity Server.

Using Postman, when I authenticate I get a bearer token. I then collect that bearer token and attach it to a new GET request, trying to hit api/webhooks/registrations (to see if I can retrieve a list of filters)

But I get the following.

```
"message": "Could not determine the user ID from the given principal.",
"exceptionMessage": "Could not determine the user ID from the given principal.",
"exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.WebHookUser.GetUserIdAsync(IPrincipal user)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Controllers.WebHookRegistrationsController.<GetUserId>d__13.MoveNext()"
```

If I ignore the webhook method and use that same credentials to access another API method, it works, so this is something specific to WebHooks Auth.

I did find this, but I cannot make it work by changing the Claims enum to something different.

[Problems registering a receiver with Microsoft Webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463157/problems-registering-a-receiver-with-microsoft-webhooks)

So, can anyone shed any light on why my identity is not working, or suggest other ways of approaching this to track the issue down?

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer in case anyone else comes across this, there isn't much information on google.
In our case, we were using a custom scope that only had 2 claims defined.

Using the linked article above, I added the following line after I had configured the custom web api.

```
            WebHookUser.IdClaimsType = Constants.CustomClaimTypes.<Claim defined in scope>;

Easy when you step back and think about the problem with fresh eyes.
```